# Installing Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, iis

After installing sharepoint on our buildserver, all of our sites in IIS didn't work anymore. Apparently Sharepoint is being installed on port 80 and everything is routed to Sharepoint. I have now changed the port to 81, but my question is if it's possible to run sharepoint on port 80 together with our normal sites? And how off course? We have experience with IIS but are not experts so please, if you explain, keep that in mind. Maybe there are some links or microsoft support on how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Ultimately you are only making things more difficult trying to run regular sites on the same url as SharePoint. Unless there is a good business reason to do so I would never do this.
Why not get an extra DNS entry in and put SharePoint on its own host header? You won't even need a DNS entry if all developers put the site in their HOSTS file.

We have lots of 'fake' dns entries like dev.project.local and build.project.local etc. Works like a charm and you never get those ugly port numbers.

Comment: I'll check this because it's, like you said, the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via Central Administration by adding it as a managed path, here's the full rundown:

[Allowing Web Applications to Coexist with Windows SharePoint Services](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/winsharepointadmin/HA011608061033.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I do this commonly for multiple sites running off the same SharePoint Front-End server.  I am using multiple zones with host headers, alternate access mapping (in central admin) and IIS bindings.  This will run multiple web applications off a single port 80. Some of these are external and have anonymous access too. Some have security rules based upon zone.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: You can easily use the same port for multiple websites on the same server **as long as you use a different website name (URL)**.
For example, you can use "ContosoWebSite.com" and "ContosoSharePoint.com" having both using the default port (80) on the same server.
To achieve that you will need to do three configurations:

- SharePoint Alternative Access Mapping.
- Configure IIS Site Binding.
- DNS (Or Hosts file for every client machine. For production environment use DNS. But for dev machines you can use the Hosts file)

**Another option** is to use the same site name (could be the server name) but with different ports.
For example, you can use "ContosoServer:80" and "ContosoServer:8875" having both using the same name (ContosoServer).

Please, do not hesitate to ask for any clarification needed.